# Latex: page n of m for \frontmatter and page n of m for \mainmatter

Tags: latex, counter

I am working on a book in latex, which uses the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter` commands from the book class. I am also using `lastpage` which gives me page n of m for the pages counted in the `\mainmatter`. How would I get the n of m page count for the `\frontmatter` using roman numerals?

Comment: Only answer to a part of the question, but redefine the command \thepage using \roman or \Roman to obtain roman numerals

Answer (score 3):

You can do by hand for the front matter what the `lastpage` package is doing for the main matter. A simple way is to put

```
\label{lastoffront}
```

somewhere that you can guarantee to be on the last page of the front matter like just before a `\clearpage` that you use before `\mainmatter`. Then, just replace the page number command in the front matter by

```
\thepage~of~\protect\pageref{lastoffront}
```

like inside the `\fancyfoot` command (I assume you're also using `fancyhdr`). You'll need to also set the page numbering style in the beginning of the main matter; the same setting works, except use the `LastPage` label provided by the `lastpage` package instead of `lastoffront`.

(This is not quite how `lastpage` handles things as the last page of the document is not always correctly determined by this technique, but I understand it is sufficient for the front matter.)